# URL reporting Availability URL in unknown to Google in GSC live test

Tags: availability

My homepage URL was removed from Google's index. When I run the live test I receive Availability - URL is unknown to Google - with N/A for all other results. (screenshot attached)

Does anyone what might be causing this?

I have checked:

Checked:

- Manual actions - none
- Security issues - none
- Robots.txt - index, follow
- Canonical - self-canonical link correct
- Indexability staus through Screaming Frog - all 200 & indexable
- SEMrsuh site audit is functioning correctly again - no issues there that would affect homepage availability

[Screenshot of GSC Live Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAqBd.png)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem except all of my pages have dropped off the index except 2.

Comment: We attempted various fixes & eventually it was solved. Due to us acting out of hast we are not sure exactly which one fix solved the problem. Here is the list of what we did, removed & replaces robots.txt ( even though was testing as okay), un-installed Autoptimize & SiteGround, marked all category & tag pages that could be considered spam as no-index.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer